# How do I force 0.0/0.0 to return zero instead of NaN in MIPSPro C compiler?

Tags: c, nan

As the question states, I am using the MIPSPRo C compiler, and I have an operation that will return NaN for some data sets where both the numerator and denom are zero. How do I keep this from happening?

Comment: `0/0` is not a number at all and it certainly is not `0`. Why would you want it to evaluate to a number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On SGI systems with the MIPSPro compiler, you can set the handling of various floating point exceptions with great precision using the facilities in `sigfpe.h`. As it happens, the division of zero by zero is one such case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sigfpe.h>

int main (void) {
    float x = 0.0f;
    (void) printf("default %f / %f = %f\n", x, x, (x / x));
    invalidop_results_[_ZERO_DIV_ZERO] = _ZERO;
    handle_sigfpes(_ON, _EN_INVALID, 0, 0, 0);
    (void) printf("handled %f / %f = %f\n", x, x, (x / x));
    return 0;
}
```

In use:

```
arkku@seven:~/test$ cc -version
MIPSpro Compilers: Version 7.3.1.3m
arkku@seven:~/test$ cc -o sigfpe sigfpe.c -lfpe
arkku@seven:~/test$ ./sigfpe
default 0.000000 / 0.000000 = nan0x7ffffe00
handled 0.000000 / 0.000000 = 0.000000
```

As you can see, setting the `_ZERO_DIV_ZERO` result changes the outcome of the same division. Likewise you can handle regular division by zero (e.g. if you don't want infinity as the result).

Of course, none of this is standard; it would be more portable to check for NaN after each division and even better to check for zeros before. C99 offers some control over the floating point environment in `fenv.h`, but I don't think anything suitable for this is available. In any case my old MIPSPro doesn't support C99.

Answer (score 9):

Use an if clause? Also I'm curious why you'd want to ignore this mathematical impossibility. You sure your input isn't wrong/meaningless in this case?

Comment: I am *not* sure that it isnt meaningless, no. I am doing a finite element solver, and occaisionally around the borders, and in the "corners" of the 3d mesh will have zeros on the numerator and denominator as a result of someone specifying zeros on those edges

Comment: I am not sure how else to handle this, other than doing a check on it. The Fortran version of this compiler does have an option to allow you to specify a value for NaN, and I assume it is for this reason?

Comment: Usually the correct way would be to ignore these points. So use that if clause I suggested to check if the values are zero.

Comment: If we were speaking of standard C, using `if` would be the best solution, but as the asker specifies MIPSPro it just happens that this specific case is supported by it… =)

Comment: Nicely spotted, +1. However I'm still wondering why Derek seemingly wants to "silently ignore" these cases. Usually when you hit something like this in math, there's something wrong with your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind introducing a small error, you can add a small value to the denominator, assuming you are doing floating point arithmetic.   apparently has some small values defined:

DBL_MIN is the smallest double

DBL_EPSILON is the smallest double s.t. x+DBL_EPSILON != x

So I would try

```
#include <float.h>
#define EPS DBL_MIN

double divModified(double num, double denom) {
    return num / (denom + EPS);
}
```

Comment: denom+DBL_MIN should be good enough. If denom is 0, denom+DBL_MIN==DBL_MIN. For pretty much any other value X large enough to care about (anything larger than 2^-2047 I should guess?), X+DBL_MIN==X, so the result should be unaffected.

Comment: There's always the problem of the denominator being _exactly_ DBL_MIN :)

Answer (score 0):

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) (the spec for floating point) says that 0.0/0.0 is not a number, i.e. `NaN`. If you want it to be anything else, by far the best approach is to detect when the operands are both zero in an `if` clause and return the value that you'd rather give. Perhaps like this:

```
#define WonkyDiv(a,b)  ((a)==0.0&&(b)==0.0 ? 0.0 : (a)/(b))

float wonkyResult = WonkyDiv(numerator, denominator);
```